# Problema con la instalacion de Netbeans 11 en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: instalacion

Instale netbeans en mi pc que funciona con ubuntu 18.04 pero al tratar de instalar unas tools cada que lo inicio me aparecen los siguientes mensajes de error, trate de desinstalar y instalar de nuevo pero no cambiar nada.
Al darle ok al error o advertencia me aparece el mismo mensaje 4 veces 
Muchas gracias 
Espero me ayuden a solucionar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

> Netbeans se encuentra disponible en los repositorios de Ubuntu, por lo
>   que si queremos tener una versión  estable de manera fácil, sólo
>   tenemos dirigirnos a la opción de Software de Ubuntu. Una vez allí no
>   tendremos más que buscar la palabra Netbeans y pulsar el botón
>   “Instalar“. Si por el contrario queremos instalar una versión más
>   reciente y personalizada, podemos hacerlo de manera manual. En este
>   artículo vamos a ver cómo instalar la última versión a día de hoy de
>   NetBeans, que es la 8.2. Esta instalación la voy a hacer sobre Ubuntu
>   18.04, aun que también se puede realizar en Debian y Linux Mint.
>
> Antes de nada hay que aclarar que para instalar la versión 8.2 de
>   Netbeans necesitamos cumplir un par de requisitos en nuestro equipo.
>   El primero es que se necesita un mínimo de 2 GB de RAM. Y que
>   tendremos que tener en nuestro equipo el Java SE Development Kit (JDK)
>   8. Es necesario para instalar este IDE. NetBeans 8.2 no se ejecuta con JDK9, y si lo hace puede producir errores.

Yo te recomiendo primero que todo eliminar el programa y luego instalarlo desde cero por terminal.

Eliminar este programa es muy sencillo. No tendremos más que dirigirnos a la carpeta que seleccionamos para la instalación. Una vez allí nos encontraremos con un archivo llamado uninstall.sh. Este será el archivo a ejecutar para eliminar por completo el IDE de nuestro equipo.  En la terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) no tendremos más que ejecutar, desde la carpeta en la que se encuentre el archivo uninstall:

```
./uninstall.sh
```

**Instalar Java JDK 8**
Un compañero ya nos habló sobre la instalación de diferentes versión de Java en nuestro sistema Ubuntu . Para instalar la versión Java 8 JDK que necesitamos, primero agregaremos el PPA webupd8team/java a nuestro sistema. Para hacerlo, abrimos una terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) y escribimos:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Una vez que se haya agregado y actualizado nuestro listado de software, buscaremos los paquetes con el nombre oracle-java8 como se muestra a continuación y terminaremos instalando:

```
apt-cache search oracle-java8
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Si tiene más de un Java instalado en tu sistema, puedes instalar el paquete oracle-java8-set-default para establecer Java 8 como predeterminado:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

**Instalar NetBeans IDE 8.2 en Ubuntu 18.04**

Ahora utilizando tu navegador preferido, dirígete a la página de descarga del IDE y descarga la última versión del instalador de NetBeans.

También se puede descargar la secuencia de comandos del instalador de NetBeans en tu sistema a través de la utilidad wget. Para ello abrimos una terminal `(Ctrl+Alt+T)` y escribimos:

```
wget -c http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Una vez completada la descarga, en el directorio de trabajo si utilizamos wget o en el lugar donde guardamos la descarga desde el navegador, encontraremos el instalador de NetBeans. Ahora utilizando el siguiente comando, haremos que el script sea ejecutable. Justo después comenzaremos con la instalación:

```
chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh     
./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Después de ejecutar los comandos anteriores, aparecerá la ‘ventana de bienvenida’ del instalador. Haremos clic en Next para continuar (o personaliza tu instalación haciendo clic en Customize) y seguir el asistente de instalación.

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar netbeans en Un Sistema Operativo de Linux 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) debes descargar e instalar las dependencias que necesita el sistema para reconocer y ejecutar las aplicaciones java...

Se instala JDK a traves de la consola o descargando el paquete de la pagina oficial...
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Debes descargar la ultima version de NetBeans
https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/index.html

Escribe sudo apt-get install [nombre del paquete a instalar]

Este procedimiento te permite tener netbeans como un programa de escritorio...

---

Hay otra forma de instalar netbeans y es accediendo al centro de software...
Una vez estando ahi buscar netbeans y saldra el programa...

Yo lo instale en ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)
Aunque preferi utilizar Eclipse, ya que su diseño le da mas fluidez al momento de programar....